# how to add a string before the last value in a printed list?

Tags: list, python-2.7

I'm new to python (2.7.3) and I am experimenting with lists. Say I have a list that is defined as:

```
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
```

I can print it with:

```
print 'the names in your list are: ' + ', '.join(my_list) + '.'
```

Which would print:

```
the names in your list are: name1, name2, name3.
```

How do i print:

`the names in your list are: name1, name2 and name3.`

Thank you.

**Update:**

I am trying logic suggested below but the following is throwing errors:

```
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']

if len(my_list) > 1:
    # keep the last value as is
    my_list[-1] = my_list[-1]
    # change the second last value to be appended with 'and '
    my_list[-2] = my_list[-2] + 'and '
    # make all values until the second last value (exclusive) be appended with a comma
    my_list[0:-3] = my_list[0:-3] + ', '

print 'The names in your list are:' .join(my_list) + '.'
```

Comment: With regards to your PS, I edited the question to make it cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
print 'The names in your list are: %s, %s and %s.' % (my_list[0], my_list[1], my_list[2])
```

The result is:

```
The names in your list are: name1, name2, and name3.
```

The `%s` is [`string formatting`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).

---

If the length of `my_list` was unknown:

```
my_list = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3']
if len(my_list) > 1: # If it was one, then the print statement would come out odd
    my_list[-1] = 'and ' + my_list[-1]
print 'The names in your list are:', ', '.join(my_list[:-1]), my_list[-1] + '.'
```

Comment: thank you, this would mean (and perhaps i should have mentioned this) that the amount of items in the list is a known amount - what if the list is dynamic and the 'instruction' that needs to be given is 'separate everything with a comma except for the last value where you separate it with 'and' (which means the second last value has no comma after it either).  i guess the functionality i am after is kind of like the 'last child' concept in css.

Comment: thank you, there is still a comma after the second last value so it currently looks like 'the names in your list are name1, name2, and name3'.

Comment: @user1063287 That's correct grammar though :) (well, either is acceptable)

Comment: i have added my attempts to make it work following the logic you suggested above, thank you.

Comment: @user1063287 You're welcome :). Feel free to accept my answer (click the tick on the left side) if it helped :D.

Comment: thank you, but my initial goal has not been achieved yet - my attempts (shown above) are not working, to clarify i am trying to get `the names in your list are: name1, name2 and name3.` thank you.

Comment: @user1063287 Done :D. Also, are we assuming that your list has a length above one the whole time? If so, I can remove that `if` statement, and if not, I can do an `else:` to change the grammar of the sentence if it was singular.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

```
def comma_and(a_list):
    return ' and '.join([', '.join(a_list[:-1]), a_list[-1]] if len(a_list) > 1 else a_list)
```

Seems to work in all cases:

```
>>> comma_and(["11", "22", "33", "44"])
'11, 22, 33 and 44'
>>> comma_and(["11", "22", "33"])
'11, 22 and 33'
>>> comma_and(["11", "22"])
'11 and 22'
>>> comma_and(["11"])
'11'
>>> comma_and([])
''
```